# how to assign proper names to array items after retrieving from CSV

Tags: php, csv

Im creating an array from a CSV file in PHP. However as expected the output is giving the an incrementation of numbers.

Here is my code

```
        $file = @fopen('customers.csv', 'r');

    // Create arrays from the CSV file
    echo '<pre>';
        while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {

            $customers[] =$line;
        }
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($customers);
```

This outputs.

```
Array
(


[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 148
        [1] => 0
        [2] => Adrian
        [3] => de Cleir


    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 305
        [1] => 0
        [2] => John 
        [3] => Smyth

    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 49
        [1] => 0
        [2] => adrian
        [3] => O'malley

    )
 )
```

when writing this information to the database it would be nicer not to be using the numbers....

e.g.

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [customer_id] => 148
        [store_id] => 0
        [first_name] => Adrian
        [second_name] => de Cleir


    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `while` loop:

```
while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {
    $customers[] = array(
        'customer_id' => $line[0],
        'store_id' => $line[1],
        'first_name' => $line[2],
        'second_name' => $line[3],
    );
}
```